# PAdES Signature Attribute signingTime forbidden

Tags: pdf, cryptography, timestamp, digital-signature, asn.1

I created a PDF PAdES signature and added a local computer timestamp ANS1/CMS Attribute `signingTime`. This works but is not valid by the [ETSI online validator](http://signatures-conformance-checker.etsi.org/protected/upload.php?sigtype=padesconf) (Registration required)
I am aware that the [ETSI Standard (page 19 table 1)](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/319100_319199/31914201/01.01.01_60/en_31914201v010101p.pdf)  defines that `signingTime` is not allowed.

1. Why is `signingTime` so bad? I do want an signed timestamp of the signature time (signed Attribute) so
2. What can I use instead (and conform to the standard)? `content-time-stamp` (signed) and `signature-time-stamp` (unsigned) seem to have a different meaning.

I do not want to use an TSP (Cryptographic timeserver).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`signing-time` is optional in CMS but it should not be used in PAdES. It should be included in the specific entry M in the Signature dictionary of the PDF document

See [ETSI specification for testing PAdES signatures](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/119100_119199/11914403/01.01.01_60/ts_11914403v010101p.pdf) section  4.2 Testing CMS digital signatures in PDF

> #PAdES/CMS/1
>
> This is the simplest CMS digital signatures in PDF with minimum requirements and **signature dictionary entry M (signing time).**

---

Note  that the signing-time is a reference of the date and time of signature obtained from the signer's device and can not be considered a reliable source of time.

---

`content-time-stamp` and `signature-time-stamp` are both RFC3161 time-stamp tokens. But  `content-time-stamp` is computed *before data is signed*, and `signature-time-stamp` **after the signature is generated** and is an unsigned attribute. A signature including `signature-time-stamp` is a PAdES-T signature

See [CAdES ETSI](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/101700_101799/101733/02.02.01_60/ts_101733v020201p.pdf) specification

- `content-time-stamp` attribute is a time-stamp token of the signed data content before it is signed, and is included as part of the signature
- `signature-time-stamp` attribute is a TimeStampToken computed on the signature value for a specific signer; it is an unsigned attribute.

Comment: I agree with your comments. I noticed that I am already using the signingTime in the PDF signature dictionary. I have a client server architecture, where the (hash signing) server has a trusted time source. 2. Question rephrased: Is there a way to add a signed timestamp in the digital signature and be conform? I fear it might be impossible without an TSP. If I use an unsigned `signature-time-stamp` I loose conformity? If I use `content-time-stamp` I need an TSP right?

Comment: You need a TimeStamp Provider to get a RFC3161 compliant timestamp in both cases. If your server has a trusted time source, you can build your own TSP. The difference between using an external "trusted" TSP and your own is that Adobe will not validate the time stamp because your certificate is not on the trusted list. But this does not mean that your PDF does not conform. If you include the time stamp certificate in the Adobe CA list, then Adobe will give it for good

Comment: I have updated the answer with a description of `content-time-stamp` and `signature-time-stamp`

Comment: Follow up question: How would I get my own TSP's certificate in the Adobe trusted list? I think there is a afford and a cost to achive becoming a trusted TSP. Would the adobe Reader evaluate to a yellow exclamation mark if my TSP Certificate is not in the Adobe list?

Comment: I do not know how the bureaucratic process is, but if you do not have a recognized and trusted CA, I do not think you can overcome the steps for Adobe to include your certificate. Certificates can be added manually by users. You could indicate your users how to do it (depending on the number of potential users this may not be a viable option)